# Load two excel data sets in Shiny after each other

Tags: r, shiny

I try to implement loading two excel data sets in Shiny with one submit button.

The user interface has a sidebar to load both data sets and three tabs to show both data sets and a ggplot figure.

When linking to the first data set, I get a sheet choice. Next I link to the second data set. Now I do not get a sheet choice until I click on the second tab in the user interface which shows the second data set.

Then I can use the upload button and both data sets are shown in tab 1 and tab 2, while tab 3 shows a plot of data set 1.

My question is, why I can't see the sheet choice menu for the second data set before I click one time the second tab in the user interface.

Best Wishes

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("Claim Overview"),

sidebarPanel(
fileInput(inputId = "iFile", label = "Claims data", accept="application/vnd.ms-excel"),
tags$hr(),
uiOutput(outputId = "ui"),

fileInput(inputId = "iFileIndex", label = "Inflation data", accept="application/vnd.ms-excel"),
tags$hr(),
uiOutput(outputId = "uiIndex"),
submitButton("Upload!", icon("refresh"))
),

mainPanel(
tabsetPanel(
  tabPanel("Claim data", dataTableOutput(outputId = "contents")),
  tabPanel("Index data", dataTableOutput(outputId = "contentsIndex")),
  tabPanel("Claim plot", plotOutput(outputId = "ClaimPlot"))
))
))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {  

chooseFile <- reactive({
inFile <- input$iFile
if (!is.null(inFile)) {
    wb <- loadWorkbook(inFile$datapath)
    sheets <- getSheets(wb)
    output$ui <- renderUI({
      list(
        selectInput(inputId = "sheet", label = "Select a sheet:", choices = sheets),
        tags$hr()
      )
    })
    return(list(path = inFile$datapath))         
} else {return(NULL)}
})  

chooseIndexFile <- reactive({
inFile <- input$iFileIndex
if (!is.null(inFile)) {
    wb <- loadWorkbook(inFile$datapath)
    sheets <- getSheets(wb)
    output$uiIndex <- renderUI({
      list(
        selectInput(inputId = "sheet", label = "Select a sheet:", choices = sheets),
        tags$hr()
      )
    })
    return(list(path = inFile$datapath))
} else {return(NULL)}    
})  

output$contents <- renderDataTable({    
objFile <- chooseFile()    
if (!is.null(objFile)) {      
    Sheet <- input$sheet        
    if (!is.null(Sheet)){                              
        wb <- loadWorkbook(objFile$path)            
        dat <- readWorksheet(wb, Sheet)            
        return(dat)            
      }           
    } else {return(NULL)}              
})

output$contentsIndex <- renderDataTable({    
objFile <- chooseIndexFile()    
if (!is.null(objFile)) {      
    Sheet <- input$sheet        
    if (!is.null(Sheet)){                                 
        wb <- loadWorkbook(objFile$path)            
        dat <- readWorksheet(wb, Sheet)            
        return(dat)            
      }                              
    } else {return(NULL)}        
})

readClaimData <- function(){    
objFile <- chooseFile()    
if (!is.null(objFile)) {      
    Sheet <- input$sheet        
    if (!is.null(Sheet)){                              
        wb <- loadWorkbook(objFile$path)            
        dat <- readWorksheet(wb, Sheet)            
        return(dat)            
      }                              
    } else {return(NULL)}        
}

readIndexData <- function(){    
objFile <- chooseIndexFile()    
if (!is.null(objFile)) {      
    Sheet <- input$sheet        
    if (!is.null(Sheet)){                                  
        wb <- loadWorkbook(objFile$path)            
        dat <- readWorksheet(wb, Sheet)            
        return(dat)            
      }                              
    } else {return(NULL)}        
}

output$ClaimPlot <- renderPlot({
x    <- readClaimData()
ggplot(data = readClaimData(), aes(x=ClaimNo, y=Claim, fill = State)) + geom_bar(colour = "black", stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) + facet_grid(Year ~ .)
})
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very easy solution:

Put `outputOptions(output, "contentsIndex", suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)`
 in `Server.R` after `output$contentsIndex`.

This stops suspending the Sheet choice option and it is then shown directly after loading the second data set.